# Error: Permission denied to access property 'CKEDITOR'

Tags: ckeditor

I have integrated browse button in ckeditor. The file is uploading but it gives "Image souce URL is missing" and not showing the image.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the CKEditor folder to the webroot of cakephp from the js folder inside the webroot and giving the full URL in CKEditor.replace function of the view file.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, most likely you're executing a [cross-domain request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), which is disallowed with a regular browser configuration due to several security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It actually turned out that the images were not uploading when I keep CKEDitor in webroot/js folder like you said may be due to security concerns , so I moved it out of the js folder.